# Host ServerSocket on Android device

Tags: android, serversocket

I'm trying to develop an app listening on a ServerSocket. When I try to connect to it from another application installed on my phone, everything works. However, it is unreachable from an external client (I am connected with 3G). Why? Is there a reason for that? How can I overcome this issue?

**EDIT**
I read that IP addresses given to smartphones by 3G providers are not public, this must be the problem.

Comment: Your 3G provider mostly will not allow you to run servers on your device. And hence blocks such connections. But then... if you don't tell what kind of ip address yoiu use..

Comment: How many kinds of ip address are there?